# javafx open derby database from method in another class

Tags: javafx, derby

We have worked with JavaFX 8 and the Derby database in other applications.
What we would like to do is put all the Create Connection Code in a Class and call the hypothetical method MakeConnection from various controller Class's 
We understand how to pass variables from one controller to another.

We assume the Connection Class is a java class and not a Controller Class?
With our limited knowledge of OOP programming it seems this might not be possible?
If this is possible what do we need to pass back to the requesting Controller to inform the call that the DB is open?
How do we code the call from the Controller?
We also assume we need a method to close the DB?

OK too many question so the answer we are looking for IS THIS POSSIBLE?
And yes if someone wants to include some pseudo code that would ge great

Answer (score 1):

Well here is some pseudo code not tested.
We created a Utility Class named JDBCUtil

```
public class JDBCUtil {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    // The URL is specific to the JDBC driver and the database you want to connect
    String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:beginningJavaDB;create=true";
    // Set the user id and password
    //String userId = "app";
    //String password = "app";
    // Get a connection
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
    // Set the auto-commit off
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    return conn;
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection conn) throws SQLException {

    if (conn != null) {
    conn.close();
    }
    }
    public static void closeStatement(Statement stmt) {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
    }
    public static void closeResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

    if (rs != null) {
    rs.close();
    }
    }
    public static void commit(Connection conn) throws SQLException {

    if (conn != null) {
    conn.commit();
    }
    }
    public static void rollback(Connection conn) throws SQLException {

    if (conn != null) {
    conn.rollback();
    }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn;
    //try{
    conn = JDBCUtil.getConnection();
    JDBCUtil.closeConnection(conn);
    }
```

As you can see we use static methods so this should work by just calling
JDBCUtil.getConnection() and JDBCUtil.closeConnection() method.
You must change the code in the
getConnection() method, which will be specific to the DBMS that you want to connect to.

While testing this code we noted original had too many try catch blocks
So we added throws SQLException in place of the try catch
This statement `stmt.close(); Is causing an ERROR and not sure why
This would help me and Grendel if anyone cares to comment please

Comment: Yes my favorite company Oracle removed Derby from JDK greater than something. I am not ready for JavaFX 11 or 12 from Gluon using it with NetBeans is a steep leaning curve Will test code but it looks great Should have waited 2 days for the BOUNTY ha ha

Comment: @James_Duh YES plodding along with JavaFX 8 I often wonder if people wait to answer to collect the BOUNTY Need to get with the times and make Desktop apps with Visual Studio and WPF Yep still on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

This line of code stmt.close() produced the error:not a statement
Well it sure looks like a statement so what else could be incorrect
Unfortunately James_Duh did not post the imports when he shared this great code
Upon close examination we noticed that we had an import that we seldom see
import java.beans.Statement; Seems that what should have been imported was this
import java.sql.Statement;
Problem solved Lesson learned if it does not look correct perhaps it is not correct!

Comment: Well It worked on my end So you had me digging to find what might have happened Guess Import Suggestion or Selection can jump up and bite Glad it is working